# Getting the previous node of a searched keyword in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document like the following:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
     <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
     <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance</title>
    <author>
     <first-name>Robert</first-name>
     <last-name>Pirsig</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>5.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Other Cities</title>
    <author>
     <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
     <last-name>Rosenbaum</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Of course, the bookstore has more than one book, so I I want to search for an author and then get returned an `XElement` for the book node that contains the searched author name.

Comment: Just the first `<book>` node or all the matching `<book>` nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var bookElements = document.Descendants("book")
    .Where(arg => arg.Element("author").Element("first-name").Value == "Benjamin")
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var bookElements = document.Descendants("first-name")
    .Where(arg => arg.Value == "Benjamin")
    .Select(arg => arg.Parent.Parent)
    .ToList();
```

[Edit] As you keep editing the question, I will edit the answer :).

To find the first book that meets the criteria:

```
var foundBookElement = document.Descendants("book")
    .Where(arg => arg.Element("author").Element("first-name").Value == "Benjamin")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`foundBookElement` will be null if none of the books match the criteria.

Comment: i need an xelement not a list

Comment: In this case, use .FirstOrDefault() instead of .ToList()

Comment: @Dominique - replace `ToList()` with `First()`.